# Default forces in multibody plant

Tags: drake

I have a trajectory optimization problem for which I found a solution. However, the plots of the forces and the trajectory, don't seem to agree unless there is another force in the plant that I did not add. The force over time is [image]
while the position over time is [image]

Unless there is some other force that is acting on the object, the position should not decrease if the force is positive everywhere. Forces like friction and drag could not do this either because they only decrease the net force but never reverse the direction. Is there another force that I am not accounting for here? There shouldn't be gravity because gravity only exists along the z axis right?

The relevant part of the urdf is shown below:

```
base_link = """
  <link name="base">

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="8 2 0.002" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="0 1 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>
"""
ball_link = """
  <link name="ball">

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" />
      <mass value="1" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".05" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="1 1 1 0.2" />
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>
"""
mass_link = """
  <link name="mass">

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" />
      <mass value="1" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".05" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>
"""
ball_joint = """
  <joint name="ball_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="base" />
    <child link="ball" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
  </joint>
"""
mass_joint = """
  <joint name="mass_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="ball" />
    <child link="mass" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit effort="1" lower="0" upper="0" />
  </joint>
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default gravity is only in the z-axis. MultibodyPlant will also implement generalized forces for damping and contact, and of course if there are multiple bodies interacting, then their dynamics can be coupled through the inertial matrix.

My best guess is that the center of mass / inertia of your body is not where you think (not in the center of the visual/collision inertia).  That's an easy mistake to make in urdf/sdf, and if you have a body that effectively has a pendulum hanging down under the ground, then it could cause mysterious behavior like this.  If you share your robot description file, then we could help more.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the relevant part of the urdf to the question. I have put the inertial origin at the center of the ball already. Is there another way in which the center of mass could be shifted?

Comment: as discussed f2f, the problem was that the ball link and the mass link both had mass.  (and part of that mass was being "left behind", not moving with the ball, and giving unintuitive results).